# 2 circuits wired to 1 outlet (not MWBC?)

Tags: electrical

I wanted some help understanding how an outlet is wired. I'm looking into this because when we use our electric kettle, our recessed lights dim and brighten quickly so I checked the outlets on the same circuit (the ones that I'm aware of).

[image]

This is not the actual j-box but the setup is similar. The black wires are tied together and have a pigtail to a standard 2-receptacle outlet - same with the white wires. No grounds (old wiring).

Sorry if my labels aren't standard labeling. I found that the wires are from 2 different circuits (hence my numbering/naming).

-2B and 2W are BOTH hot. However, when 2W is connected to 7W (whites tied together), it is no longer hot.

-7B is hot. 7W is not hot, as normal.

With both circuits on at the breakers, I pulled out 2B from the Wago connector and my fixtures on circuit 2 (outlets, lights) turned off.

At first I thought it might be a MWBC but 1) the black wires were all tied together (same with white) and pigtailed to the outlet and 2) the tab on the outlet was NOT broken off anyway.

Did someone in the past screw up or did they do this intentionally? Do I need to get this fixed? (Concern for safety). FYI I don't plan on fixing this myself because clearly I don't know what's going on. I just want to know more in case I need to get it fixed by an electrician.

Comment: Are you determining ‘hot’ with a multimeter or a non-contact tester or something else?

Comment: If 2W is hot and you tie it to 7W which is neutral, either you have created a dead-short that should immediately trip your breakers, or the measurement of 2W was incorrect (phantom voltage).

Comment: Please provide more information as to how you are determining what is hot:  meter or noncontact indicator?  If meter, measured between what two points?  How did you identify the two breakers you believe are connected?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Dead short *assuming standard breaker numbering*. Sometimes people apply non-standard numbering, such as when tandem breakers are present. A photo or the panel would be helpful.

Comment: Pictures of *your* actual panel and of *your* actual receptacle junction box would be helpful.

Comment: @nobody, I wasn't assuming any breaker numbering. I referred to the labels that the OP used in their Q. And wirenutting any hot to any neutral creates a dead short.

Answer (score 1):

> 2B and 2W are BOTH hot.

This could be a serious problem with the wiring.

However, it is just as likely that you're measuring the wires incorrectly.  In this situation as in most, 2W would not be considered "hot" unless a multimeter reads voltage between the 2W wire and the bare ground wire.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you find a branch circuit that is as you say is fed by two circuit breakers, that is definitely a dangerous condition that you need to address immediately: turn both breakers off and call an electrician.

Have them assess the rest of your wiring (and tell them of any other peculiarities) because there may be other dangers as well, because whoever wired that branch that way was incompetent and may have made other mistakes.

Just as important, someone else who was competent and made subsequent modifications correctly may have assumed a circuit they were connecting to was correctly wired when it was not.  That could have made manifest a danger that previously was latent.

There are other steps you could take to analyze the situation, but they are complicated and given your stated limited knowledge and intent to have an electrician correct the situation, you should proceed without delay.